# Accessing variables initialized inside eval

Tags: r, scope

Can someone explain how to access variables created within an `eval` statement? I know there are many other solutions to this problem, but I am trying to understand why I am running into a scope issue here.

Error

```
Error in paste0("fit<-summary(lm(NPISplit~", x, ",data=df));rs<-round(fit$r.squared,3);pv<-round(fit$coefficients[,4],3);if(pv<0.05){paste(",  : 
object 'rs' not found
```

Code

```
df<-data.frame(NPISplit=c(0,0,0,1,1,1),Happiness=c(2,5,6,8,7,4))
moods<-c('Happiness')
lapply(moods,function(x){
    eval(parse(text=paste0(
        "fit<-summary(lm(NPISplit~",x,",data=df));rs<-round(fit$r.squared,3);pv<-round(fit$coefficients[,4],3);if(pv<0.05){paste(",x,"=",rs,"&",pv,")}")))
    })
```

Comment: Looks like a failure to understand R programming. I suggest you provide the missing information to allow the code to actually run, unless of course you cannot see immediately that `rs` and not to mention `x`, `fit`, `pv`)  is/are nowhere to be seen. Try `fortunes::fortune("parse")`

Comment: Functions evaluate from the inside out. Here, `paste0`, then `parse`, then `eval`. You're trying to `paste0` `rs`, but it won't be defined for another two steps. You could split your `eval(parse(...))` in two, but there are better ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to escape quotes inside of quotes.

```
x <- 1
lapply(1:2, function(.) eval(parse(text="y<-x+1;paste(\"y=\", y)")))
```

Comment: Single quotes work too. And agreed, this is a really unpleasant way to code.